# highchart range selector to show bus trip details

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, chart.js

I need to show bus schedule details in a graph with following details

1. X axis should display stop Name, and the stop names are fetching from database
2. Y axis should display time
3. A range selector is required to filter the time range.

Below given a sample image of my requirement

[image: sample graph]

Comment: For now I think that you should be able to use heatmap to meet your requirement, however without a mock-up showing what you want to achieve  and some more detailed information about your chart it is hard to give you proper answer. What have you tried for now? Do you have a live example of your current chart, like jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi,
I need something similar to this.
https://jsfiddle.net/schme16/xfyvvup8/20/

Here the x axis values are constants. I need y axis as stop names x as time. and need to draw each trip in that chart

Comment: You should be able to achieve similar chart using highcharts.js library: http://jsfiddle.net/nokzn3u4/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot Grzegorz Blachliński.. i will check it and will update you .I need to include range selector also. Will try and update you the feedback

Comment: Hi,
I have tried using the reference you provided. but i am not getting the values in required format. Could you please help me to solve the issue
Please refer the below link for checking my code
https://jsfiddle.net/VidyaSajeev/b8whv9vx/

Comment: I have used a single record to test it. In my application I have to draw approximately 150 trips like this. that is the reason for choosing range selector. Which is not included in current sample.

Comment: It looks that you had problems with your creating your "st" date number: https://jsfiddle.net/b8whv9vx/1/